# Why do prime numbers in modulo result in more uniform distributions?

Tags: number-theory, uniform-distribution

Let us assume a sequence as follows:

$S_{n} = (S_{n-1} * c_{1} + c_{2})\text{ mod } m$

This is the pseudorandom generator found in most programming languages' random function.

It is known that a prime $m$ results in a more uniform distribution of random numbers, as a result of a larger period for $S_{n}$. As a result, $m$ is typically a prime number.

Why do prime numbers typically result in larger periods than factorable numbers for modulo arithmetic?

Comment: Have you seen the closed form formula for $S_n$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I haven't; I'll look that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), the period is at most $m$, and is equal to $m$ only if

1. $\gcd(c_2,m)=1$,
2. $p\mid m$ implies $p\mid c_1-1$ for all prime $p$, and
3. $4\mid m$ implies $4\mid c_1-1$.

So $m$ needn't be prime, but it's easiest to meet and to check these conditions if it is.

Comment: That's interesting. I'm curious how the proof of those three lemmas work, but I suppose I shall have to read [the paper!](http://goo.gl/nEk4D) Thank you!